# How to configure rhino to run jasmine tests for angularjs controllers

Tags: angularjs, scala, sbt, rhino

I am having trouble getting unit tests working for an Angular JS app using Jasmine sbt plugin.

when I add angular.js ( ver 1.3.1) to test.dependecies.js

```
EnvJasmine.loadGlobal(EnvJasmine.libDir + "/angular.js");
EnvJasmine.loadGlobal(EnvJasmine.libDir + "/ui-bootstrap-0.11.2.js");
EnvJasmine.loadGlobal(EnvJasmine.testDir + "/lib/angular-mocks.js");
```

I got the following error

> [  Envjs/1.6 (Rhino; U; Linux amd64 3.13.0-32-generic; en-US; rv:1.7.0.rc2) Resig/20070309 PilotFish/1.2.13  ]
>   Could not read file: /opt/scala/myproject/src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/angular.js
>    error was: TypeError: Cannot find function querySelector in object [object HTMLDocument].

I cant figure if there is a compatibility issue with angular and rhino or in jasmine config

Comment: Running modern applications (angular/backbone) tests server-side using rhino and/or htmlunit is something I once tryed. But using node (and a REAL JS engine) to launch the tests is, in my opinion, the easiest and fastest way. rhino is simply not up to date with latests specs and this may be a very, very long road for you, with a strong chance to find a wall at the end.

Comment: Hi there. Have you solved the problem using Rhino? I have the same issue and thinking whether it worth efforts or it's better to go with Karma.

Comment: I'm sure it is way too late for the OP, but there is now [an issue open](https://github.com/joescii/sbt-jasmine-plugin/issues/7) against sbt-jasmine-plugin.  I doubt it is rhino as much as it is env.js.  As @PierreGayvallet pointed out, the rhino/env.js combo sadly are dead projects fading on the horizon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a maintained project such as Domino:

> Domino is based on work by Mozilla's Andreas Gal and appears to be currently maintained. While it didn't work out of the box, it was easy to patch. The modifications which I made were as follows:

```
    Change files to use AMD style loading instead of CommonJS (so I can load them in Rhino and the browser using RequireJS)
    Add xmlns attribute to SVG element when serializing
    Modified the CSS parser to workaround a issue in Rhino with case insensitive regular expressions
    Added a SVG element type which has a style property like the HTML elements
    Added SVG specific CSS properties to the CSS parser
    Several bug fixes
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject;
import org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Global;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;

public abstract class RunJS {
    static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(RunJS.class);

    static final int JS_VERSION = Context.VERSION_1_8;
    static final int OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 9;

    private static ScriptableObject ENVIRONMENT = null;

    static {
        ENVIRONMENT = createNewEnvironment();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a top level scope with the shell globals and requirejs then loads
     * bootstrap.js
     * 
     * The bootstrap script can then load other modules to be included in the top level
     * scope using requirejs
     */
    public static ScriptableObject createNewEnvironment() {
        Global global = null;

        Context cx = Context.enter();
        try {
            cx.setOptimizationLevel(OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL);
            cx.setLanguageVersion(JS_VERSION);

            global = new Global();
            global.setSealedStdLib(true);
            global.init(cx);

            Scriptable argsObj = cx.newArray(global, new Object[] {});
            global.defineProperty("arguments", argsObj, ScriptableObject.DONTENUM);

            // Enable RequireJS
            loadJS(cx, global, "/path/to/r.js");

            // Load the bootstrap file
            loadJS(cx, global, "/path/to/bootstrap.js");

            global.sealObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error setting up Javascript environment", e);
        }
        finally {
            Context.exit();
        }
        return global;
    }

    public static void loadJS(Context cx, Scriptable scr, String fileName) throws Exception {
        Reader reader;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)), Charsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new Exception("Could not find file", e);
        };

        try {
            cx.evaluateReader(scr, reader, fileName, 0, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception("IO error reading file", e);
        }
        finally {
            try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Exception("IO error closing file", e);
            }
        }
    }

    protected static Scriptable getScope(Context cx) {
        Scriptable scope = cx.newObject(RunJS.ENVIRONMENT);
        scope.setPrototype(RunJS.ENVIRONMENT);
        scope.setParentScope(null);
        return scope;
    }
}

boostrap.js

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base/path/to/packages'
});

var window, document, d3;

require(['domino/index'], function(domino) {
    window = domino.createWindow('');
    document = window.document;

    require(['d3/d3'], function(_d3) {
        d3 = _d3;
    });
});

// preload your modules
require(["mypackage/mymodule1", "mypackage/mymodule2"]);

Subclass RunJS and load your JavaScript file like this:

Context cx = Context.enter();
try {
    cx.setOptimizationLevel(OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL);
    cx.setLanguageVersion(JS_VERSION);

    Scriptable scope = getScope(cx);
    scope.put("myvar", scope, myvar);
    loadJS(cx, scope, "/path/to/yourcode.js");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error(e);
}
finally {
    Context.exit();
}
```

**References**

- [Server side SVG generation using D3.js | jazdw.net](http://jazdw.net/content/server-side-svg-generation-using-d3js)
- [Domino (Patched with SVG Support)](https://github.com/jazdw/domino)