# sbt and scala.js (with Node.js) can't run with a local .js dependency due to "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I need help with an error when I run using sbt, scala.js, a local bit of javascript code on Node.js.

```
[info] Running net.walend.graph.results.PlotTime
Hello from scala
[error] /Users/dwalend/projects/ScalaGraphMinimizer/toGhPages/target/scala-2.11/toghpages-fastopt.js:1854
[error]   $g["hello"]();
[error]              ^
[error] TypeError: undefined is not a function
[error]     at $c_Lnet_walend_graph_results_PlotTime$.main__V (/Users/dwalend/projects/ScalaGraphMinimizer/toGhPages/target/scala-2.11/toghpages-fastopt.js:1854:14)
[error]     at $c_Lnet_walend_graph_results_PlotTime$.$$js$exported$meth$main__O (/Users/dwalend/projects/ScalaGraphMinimizer/toGhPages/target/scala-2.11/toghpages-fastopt.js:1861:8)
[error]     at $c_Lnet_walend_graph_results_PlotTime$.main (/Users/dwalend/projects/ScalaGraphMinimizer/toGhPages/target/scala-2.11/toghpages-fastopt.js:1864:15)
[error]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dwalend/projects/ScalaGraphMinimizer/toGhPages/target/scala-2.11/toghpages-launcher.js:2:107)
[error]     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
[error]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
[error]     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
[error]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
[error]     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
[error]     at require (module.js:384:17)
org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: node.js exited with code 1
      at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$AbstractExtRunner.waitForVM(ExternalJSEnv.scala:96)
      at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$ExtRunner.run(ExternalJSEnv.scala:143)
      at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$.org$scalajs$sbtplugin$ScalaJSPluginInternal$$jsRun(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:479)
      at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$45$$anonfun$apply$27$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:539)
      at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$45$$anonfun$apply$27$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:533)
      at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
```

I'm most suspicious of my build.sbt. (It's in a subproject that has no scala.js in it.) I think I have something out of joint, but don't know what other settings to try.

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation","-feature")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.8.1"
)

//don't need phantomjs . //jsDependencies += RuntimeDOM

jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "d3js" % "3.5.5-1" / "d3.min.js"

jsDependencies += ProvidedJS / "algorithmTime.js"

scalaJSStage in Global := FastOptStage

persistLauncher := true
```

I'm not able to even get a "hello" out of algorthmTime.js with Node.js.

```
function hello() {
  console.log("hello from js")
}
```

The main() in Scala pretty trim:

object PlotTime extends js.JSApp {

```
def main(): Unit = {
  println("Hello from scala")
  global.hello()

  val png = global.dataToPng("benchmark/results/v0.1.2/dijkstra.csv")
  println(png)
}
```

}

Before trying Node.js I got a bit further using phantom.js and Rhino. sbt run gets into my local javascript code and stalls inside of d3 with

```
[info] Running net.walend.graph.results.PlotTime
Hello from scala
hello from js
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "querySelector" of undefined (/Users/dwalend/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars/d3js/jars/d3js-3.5.5-1.jar#META-INF/resources/webjars/d3js/3.5.5/d3.min.js#3)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3701)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3679)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3707)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3726)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3743)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2269)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2262)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1317)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3102)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:120)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1078)
  at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.package$ContextOps$.evaluateFile$extension(package.scala:21)
  at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv.org$scalajs$jsenv$rhino$RhinoJSEnv$$internalRunJS(RhinoJSEnv.scala:157)
  at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv$Runner.run(RhinoJSEnv.scala:62)
  at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$.org$scalajs$sbtplugin$ScalaJSPluginInternal$$jsRun(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:479)
  at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$45$$anonfun$apply$27$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:539)
  at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$45$$anonfun$apply$27$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:533)
  at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last toGhPages/compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while running JS code: TypeError: Cannot call method "querySelector" of undefined (/Users/dwalend/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars/d3js/jars/d3js-3.5.5-1.jar#META-INF/resources/webjars/d3js/3.5.5/d3.min.js#3)
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv.org$scalajs$jsenv$rhino$RhinoJSEnv$$internalRunJS(RhinoJSEnv.scala:173)
  at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv$Runner.run(RhinoJSEnv.scala:62)
  at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$.org$scalajs$sbtplugin$ScalaJSPluginInternal$$jsRun(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:479)
  at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$45$$anonfun$apply$27$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:539)
  at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$45$$anonfun$apply$27$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:533)
  at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
```

This error suggests my code is doing what it is supposed to. However, the internet wisdom says [chasing in Rhino "querySelector" is a dead end and Node.js is a better choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799364/how-to-configure-rhino-to-run-jasmine-tests-for-angularjs-controllers).

I suspect I'm missing some sbt switch in the system, but don't know what else to look for.

I also don't see how it *should* work. I'm new to javascript, but I don't see how any one  of these javascript files depends on any other in any of the produced files. (The examples on [scala.js's tutorial](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial.html) link everything together using script tags in an index.html page.)

```
> tree toGhPages/target/scala-2.11/
toGhPages/target/scala-2.11/
├── classes
│   ├── JS_DEPENDENCIES
│   ├── algorithmTime.js
│   └── net
│       └── walend
│           └── graph
│               └── results
│                   ├── PlotTime$.class
│                   ├── PlotTime$.sjsir
│                   └── PlotTime.class
├── toghpages-fastopt.js
├── toghpages-fastopt.js.map
└── toghpages-jsdeps.js
```

The big picture: I'm attempting to use sbt, scala.js, and d3 to create performance charts for a scala graph algorithm library. The first cut of charts look promising, but github doesn't support javascript on README.md pages. For that I'll need a simple image. I want to learn more about both scala.js and d3 which attracted me to this approach.

Comment: You are hitting one of Scala.js' fundamental limitations of importing other JavaScript (which is not standardized in ES5, so we can only rely on heuristics). I don't have time to write up a full answer today. I'll write a detailed answer tomorrow (PST).

Comment: I look forward to it. Thanks!

Comment: I was realizing, as I looked at this again, that this likely *shouldn't* work on Node.js -- querySelector is a DOM function, which I wouldn't expect to see implemented in Node.I'd recommend trying this on PhantomJS again, using the *non*-minified version of D3, and seeing whether you can get a line number there. I think that's the real issue: D3 is trying to call a method on what amounts to a null pointer, based on the error message...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Quickfix**

In order to work in Node.js, do not properly declare the members you want to be visible (i.e. no `var` or named `function`):

```
hello = function() {
  console.log("hello from js")
};
```

This is a **terrible** hack, but will solve the inclusion problems for `algorithmTime.js`. "Proper" solution at the end.

**Background**

Composing different JavaScript files in a general is hard, since there exists no standardized way of doing so. Traditional HTML-include tags just have the semantics of concatenating all the code. This is the semantics we try to emulate in the Scala.js runners.

However, Node.js uses the [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) module system. In that system, a library explicitly exports members and the using site puts them into a namespace. This avoids naming collisions.

Example:

```
// Library (foo.js)
exports.foo = function() { return 1; };

// Using code
var lib = require("foo.js");
lib.foo() // returns 1
```

This allows the library to declare local values without leaking them into the caller. (Note aside: Although we have a function called `require` here, this is **not** [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)).

However, in the Scala.js runners, where we are expected to "just include" `foo.js`, this poses a challenge. What name should we use for the result of the `require` call? This is what `commonJSName` is means (see below for example).

If `commonJSName` for a given dependency is not set, in the Node.js runner, we will just emit

```
require(<name.js>);
```

without assigning it to anything. (Why not just dump the file you say? Goodbye reasonable stacktraces).

This has a very interesting effect in `Node.js`. Consider the following file (`bar.js`):

```
var a = 1;
b = 2;
```

Now we do:

```
require("bar.js")
console.log(a); // undefined
console.log(b); // 2
```

It seems that the `b` leaks into the global context whereas `a` does not. This is why the quickfix works.

**Solutions**

For a better solution, you have two choices:

1. Commit to Node.js, write your library specific to its module system
2. Autodetect the environment you are included in and adapt dynamically (many JS libraries do this)

**Solution 1**

```
modules.exports = function() {
  console.log("hello from js")
};
```

Add `commonJSName` to your dependency:

```
jsDependencies += ProvidedJS / "algorithmTime.js" commonJSName "hello"
```

This will fail miserably in anything but Node.js for two reasons:

1. The JS VM might not support CommonJS style includes
2. Overriding the full `exports` namespace like that is not standard CommonJS but specific to Node.js (IIRC).

**Solution 2**

Autodetect:

```
var hello = {};

// Scope to prevent leakage
(function(exp) {
  hello.hello = function() {
    console.log("hello from js");
  }
})(exports ? exports : hello);
```

You will also need to set `commonJSName` in this case.

Further, you might already suspect from the code, that this requires you to have an additional indirection, since CommonJS requires the top-level export to be an object (IIRC). Therefore you need to adapt your Scala.js code:

```
global.hello.hello();
```

However, if your library exports multiple symbols, this is probably a good idea anyway. Further, this is likely to work in most JS environments (and should work in the three environments we provide with Scala.js).

**Epilogue**

We (the Scala.js team) are very unhappy about this situation since we believe that including JS libraries should be just as easy as depending on other Scala and/or Java libraries in JVM land. However, we have not found a better solution to this short of supporting **every** inclusion style, which is a huge design, engineering and certainly maintenance effort (what if a system changes or a new system comes up?).

Related discussions: [#457](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/457) and [#706](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/706).

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix and the deep explanation. The quick fix worked!  Unfortunately, I'm all the way back to hello from js
  [error] [stdin]:27
  [error] t}:function(n,t){for(var e in t)n[e]=t[e]},Ma=function(n,t){return t.querySele
  [error]
  [error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
  [error]     at Ma ([stdin]:27:9927)
  [error]     at Object.ta.select ([stdin]:27:15439)
  [error]     at plotIt   (.../target/scala-2.11/classes/algorithmTime.js:27:18)
  [error]     at dataToPng (.../target/scala-2.11/classes/algorithmTime.js:99:5)